# Using an unordered_map where Key is a member of T

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, unordered-map

Is there any nice way to use an unordered_map so that you can access objects by a member variable in constant time (average case)? The following example has this functionality but requires the name of each `Person` to be duplicated as the Key:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <algorithm>

class Person {
 public:
  Person() : name_("") {}
  Person(const std::string& name) : name_(name) {}
  std::string getName() const { return name_; }
  void kill() const { std::cout << name_ << " is dead!" << std::endl; }
 private:
  std::string name_;
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
  Person p1("dave");
  Person p2("bob");

  std::unordered_map<std::string, Person> map = {
    {p1.getName(), p1}, // Duplicating the
    {p2.getName(), p2}  // keys here
  };

  map["dave"].kill();
  return 0;
}
```

I'm thinking that somehow the `value_type` would need to be `Person` itself, instead of a `pair<string, Person>` and the `unordered_map` would need to know to use `Person::getName` when hashing and accessing objects.

The ideal solution would allow me to set up an `unordered_map` (or `unordered_set` if it's more apt for the job) that knows to use `Person::getName` to get the key of each object. I would then be able to insert them simply by giving the object (and no key because it knows how to get the key) and access them by giving keys that would compare equal to the return value of `Person::getName`.

Something along the lines of:

```
// Pseudocode
std::unordered_map<Person, Person::getName> map = {p1, p2};
map["dave"].kill();
```

So is it possible to instantiate an `unordered_map` template class that can do this neatly?

Comment: I don't know whether I understood the question correctly.. is `unordered_set` is the container you are looking for?

Comment: I edited the question to give an idealistic piece of code. I don't believe `unordered_set` meets this spec (at least not with its most basic usage).

Comment: Call me crazy, but how about using a Boost.bimap where you make the right-hand side an `unordered_multimap`? Then you get right-to-left lookup in the complexity of that container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not opposed to using [Boost](http://www.boost.org/), then [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/libs/multi_index/) makes this extremely simple without adding any needless inefficiency. Here's an example that effectively creates an `unordered_set` of `Person` objects that is keyed on the value of `Person::getName()`:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/indexed_by.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/mem_fun.hpp>

namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;

struct Person
{
    Person() = default;
    Person(std::string const& name) : name_(name) { }
    std::string const& getName() const noexcept { return name_; }
    void kill() const { std::cout << name_ << " is dead!\n"; }

private:
    std::string name_;
};

typedef bmi::multi_index_container<
    Person,
    bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::hashed_unique<
            bmi::const_mem_fun<Person, std::string const&, &Person::getName>
        >
    >
> PersonUnorderedSet;

int main()
{
    Person p1("dave");
    Person p2("bob");

    PersonUnorderedSet set;
    set.insert(p1);
    set.insert(p2);

    set.find("dave")->kill();

    // for exposition, find is actually returning an iterator
    PersonUnorderedSet::const_iterator iter = set.find("bob");
    if (iter != set.end())
        iter->kill();

    // set semantics -- newly_added is false here, because
    // the container already contains a Person named 'dave'
    bool const newly_added = set.insert(Person("dave")).second;
}
```

(Note that I changed the signature of `Person::getName()` to return by `const`-reference rather than by value for efficiency's sake, but the change isn't strictly required.)

---

It should be noted that C++14's support for [transparent comparators](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20317413/636019) would allow you to use `std::unordered_set<Person>` here without any need for Boost.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious solution is to just duplicate the key part, and use
`std::unordered_map`; for small, localized use, this is the simplest and
the preferred solution, but there is nothing enforcing the invariant
`key == mapped.key_part`, which make the code harder to maintain when 
insertions may occur at several different places in the code.

If you're keeping pointers in the map, rather than values, then you can
wrap the map to arrange for the key to be a pointer to the appropriate
field in the value.  The problem with this is, of course, that it means
keeping pointers, and not values.

If you don't modify the values once they're in the map, you can just use
`std::set`, rather than `std::map`, with an appropriate hash and
equality function.  If you do this, you'll probably have to construct a
dummy `Person` object in order to access the data.

If you want to modify the values (excluding the key, of course), then
you have the problem that `std::set` only provides `const` access to its
members.  You can get around this using `const_cast`, but it's ugly.
(And error prone; how do you ensure that the actual key part isn't
modified.)

None of this solutions is entirely satisfactory.  In a case like yours,
where there's no mutable access to the key part (the name), I'd probably
go with one of the first two solutions, wrapping the `unordered_map` in
a class of my own to ensure that the invariants were maintained.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is an `unordered_set`, not a map. The set uses the value as both key and value.

Just don't change the "key" part of the value.

Comment: Lookup in an `unordered_set` is `O(1)` average case but `O(b.size())` worst case.

Comment: Wouldn't I then have to access the values in the set by using the values themselves? Ideally, I'd like to access them by member. i.e. rather than map[p1], map["dave"]. Unless there's a nice way of instantiating an unordered_set that does this.

Comment: @Tomalak Average case is what I'm going for. (I added that detail to the question)

Comment: @sftrabbit, the lookup is controlled by how you hashing works, if you've provided a hasher for `Person`, you'd need to construct a dummy Person object with the key(s) used by the hasher. The lookup will happen using this dummy and you'll get an iterator to the real instance. So your lookup would be `some_set.find(Person("dave"));` assuming that the hasher only works on the name attribute of Person. But the important point as Nicol says is, *don't change the key!*

Comment: `unordered_set` provides no write access to the objects it contains, so you can't modify the key (or anything else) without a `const_cast`.